# Out of memory using mpirun and Python subprocess

Tags: python, memory, mpi, slurm

I am writing a wrapper code in Python to synchronize the execution of multiple applications in a SLURM system.

When using SLURM directly with one application, the job runs without problem.
With the `sacct` command, I can determine that the maximum memory was (MaxRSS) 8.2 GB out of 96 GB available. The command used in the sbatch file was of the form:

```
mpirun -np 4 --map-by ppr:1:node:pe=20 executable
```

Now, if I use a simple Python wrapper and pass `python3 simple_wrapper.py`, the wrapper being:

```
import subprocess
import sys
with open('log', 'w') as out:
    cmd = 'mpirun -np 4 --map-by ppr:1:node:pe=20 executable'
    subprocess.check_call(cmd.split(), bufsize=-1, stdout=out, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

The executable throws me a problem of memory allocation.
However, checking with `sacct` the memory allocation is of 5 GB.

Is it a common issue that people have when executing a MPI application on a cluster with  Python3? How to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: try writing a trivial shell script that outputs the same amount than your MPI job, run it under your wrapper and measure the overhead of your python wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. 
Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but may I ask what kind of shell script I should write, and when you say same amount, do mean memory? And how would it measure the overhead that way, by running this python script with and without mpirun?
Something I should say is that the whole wrapper is included in my post, nothing else. I have a hard time understanding what is causing memory to go up by 90GB or making SLURM run out of memory.

Comment: write the same amount to `stdout` and `stderr` than your MPI program. please also post the exact error message.

Comment: Oh, the total content of stdout is 52K. The process also outputs (in debug mode) the content of all outputs for each node. Each of them is very similar, except one which contains the following error: "Fatal error in function Mem: Memory allocation failed (calloc, 26214400, 8, 6152.92)", which in the solver means "out of memory".

Comment: MPI then gives the following std error: -------------------------------------------------------
Primary job  terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code.. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
-------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status, thus causing
the job to be terminated. The first process to do so was:

  Process name: [[13991,1],3]
  Exit code:    255

Comment: keep in mind `sacct` may or may not work depending on how MPI is integrated with SLURM. How many nodes in your job? if a single node, you'd rather run `top -b` or something in the background in order to manually check how much memory is allocated, both with and without the wrapper.

Comment: The executable only works with >3 nodes (it divides the memory required per node), so I am using 4 nodes, which corresponds to the -np argument I put above. Therefore, unfortunately, I cannot use top. Instead, I was using wwall -j <job_id> and it gave me very similar numbers (~8-10 GB over 96GB). Do you have other suggestions? I really appreciate you taking some time for me.

Comment: does the memory error occurs on the first node? if so, you can `top -b &` or similar before invoking your wrapper

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, but rather on other nodes usually.